# Nested IF with loop

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a new value in column "AL" based on the criteria/value in column R and AL. I am not an expert in VBA and I have written the below after googling, it is working but wondering how can I improvise the speed. This code is taking little longer than expected, seems like keep looking for each condition, any advice would be grateful.

```
For Each cel In Range("R5:R" & wsSB.Range("F1000").End(xlUp).Row)

        If cel.Value <> "" Then
            If cel.Value = "per visit" And cel.Offset(0, 20).Value = "PROF" Then cel.Offset(0, 20).Value = "D001"
                ElseIf cel.Value = "per visit" And cel.Offset(0, 20).Value = "ER7O" Then cel.Offset(0, 20).Value = "ER01"
                ElseIf cel.Value = "per day" And cel.Offset(0, 20).Value = "OPFAC" Then cel.Offset(0, 20).Value = "OPS1"
                ElseIf cel.Value = "per day" And cel.Offset(0, 20).Value = "IPFAC" Then cel.Offset(0, 20).Value = "APD1"
                ElseIf cel.Value = "per admission" Then cel.Offset(0, 20).Value = "ADMT"
            Else: cel.Offset(0, 20).Value = ""
        End If
    Next
    End If
```

Comment: Wrong place buddy. If code works, please refer to Code Review.

Comment: Where/ How can I place for code review?

Comment: [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: This may be on-topic for [codereview.se] as long as **A**, it works, **B** it's not hypothetical or incomplete in any way

Comment: Let me try then because it meets both the criteria in my opinion, for now I have used excel formula because that is faster than this.